# Why won't my .length method work with Array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, morse-code

```
public class MorseCodeTranslator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] letter = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String [] morse = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----"};
    System.out.println("Enter in some words or letter to convert them to morse code : ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String english = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println(english.toLowerCase());



    for(int i = 0; i < english.length(); i++){
        char test = english.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < letter.length(); j++){
            if(letter.charAt(j) == test){
                System.out.print(morse[j]);
              }
          }
      }










    /*** SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT
     * 
     * Please enter some text: Hello World
     * Morse Code: .... . .-.. .-.. --- .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
     */

}
```

I need to convert English letters that the user inputs into Morse code. I want it to take the length of letter[] and compare it to the indexes of morse[], then to print out the Morse code counterpart. But I get an error at "letter.length();" saying "cannot find symbol- method length()". It works where "english.length();" is. Is there another way to do this with Arrays?

Comment: Because length is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 7):

On arrays, `length` is a property, so you just say `letter.length`. On a `String`, it is a method, so there you say `english.length()`.